# .NET Core 2.1 - Entity Framework: Check for duplicates before adding to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

In my SQL Server DB, I have a table of IOT data (nearing 1,000,000 records). When the app receives inbound readings, I want to check that the DB doesn't already have a reading for that device with the same timestamp. What is the fastest way to check for records with matching properties?

**Model**

```
public class Reading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Measurement { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

**AddReading Method**

```
public class ReadingRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public ReadingRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void AddReading(Reading reading)
    {
        // my proposed method... is there a better way?
        if (!_context.Readings.Any(r =>
            r.DeviceId == reading.DeviceId,
            r.Timestamp == reading.Timestamp))
            _context.Readings.Add(reading);
    }
}
```

Comment: `SqlCommands` are an option to cut your round trips in half.  Could create a DataContext method along lines of `AddReadingIfNotExists(Reading reading)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way is to insert and have a unique index blow and react to the error message.

Alternative do use a stored procedure.

Anything you do with EF will per definition NOT be fastest choice. And yes, this does not mean abandoning it all - EF is good for 80% to 95% of operations. Just bypass it for this one.

Comment: [reference for creating stored procedures](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely something I'll have to think about doing. The readings do come in a large list via an API request and are first stored in a `List<Reading>` so I could check the list on itself, and that would probably do the trick. If I were to compare incoming lists against each other, I would suspect that I'd have to find a way to store the list of incoming readings in a variable that can persist across sessions.

Comment: Actually if you get LISTS anyway, then upload the lists to a temp or other staging table via SqlBulkCopy (i..e. allow doubles as per your rule) and then use ONE sp to move them to final storage.Suddenly a thread should be able to handle 50k rows in a second (actual number here) and you can use multiple threads / parallel requests. Eliminate doubles in the select.... from the select...into part.